# Can't initlized contract class in mythrill

Tags: mythril

I'm doing my first steps in mythril.
Here is the code I'm trying to run:

`from mythril.ether.soliditycontract import SolidityContract
from mythril.laser.ethereum import svm
contract = SolidityContract("./examples/rubixi.sol", "Rubixi")`

But I get the following error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/PycharmProjects/untitled/p.py", line 4, in 
    contract = SolidityContract("./examples/rubixi.sol", "Rubixi")
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mythril/ether/soliditycontract.py", line 99, in init
    super().init(code, creation_code, name=name)
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mythril/ether/ethcontract.py", line 20, in init
    self.disassembly = Disassembly(self.code, enable_online_lookup=enable_online_lookup)
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mythril/disassembler/disassembly.py", line 50, in init
    signatures.write()  # store resolved signatures (potentially resolved online)
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mythril/support/signatures.py", line 129, in write
    self.signatures_file_lock.aquire()  # try to aquire it within the next 10s
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mythril/support/signatures.py", line 40, in aquire
    self.lockfile.touch(mode=0o0000, exist_ok=False)  # touch the lockfile
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/pathlib.py", line 1236, in touch
    fd = self._raw_open(flags, mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/pathlib.py", line 1044, in _raw_open
    return self._accessor.open(self, flags, mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/pathlib.py", line 387, in wrapped
    return strfunc(str(pathobj), *args)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/username/.mythril/signatures.json.lck'`